# @DateTimeFormat conversion error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a RESTful @Controller where I'm attempting to convert an incoming string into a Date object

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a")
private Date start;
```

The incoming string: "10/01/2013 03:05 AM"

And in controller:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
System.out.println("Start date:" + format.format(p.getStart()));
```

Output: "01/10/2013 03:05 AM"

what's wrong with this code?

Comment: It's not clear what your input and output are here - what you want, or what you're getting?

Comment: My input is string: 10/01/2013 03:05 AM
In controller, when printing out the date, output: 01/10/2013 03:05 AM.

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
  System.out.println("Start date:" + format.format(p.getStart()));

Comment: How are you printing out the date in your controller? Bear in mind that a `Date` value doesn't have a format in itself...

Comment: to get things clear, you are passing string "10/01/2013 03:05 AM" , spring converts its into a Data object, now in controller you are again converting that date object back to String ?... Also can you debug and confirm that start Date object is getting populated fine ?

Comment: The start value: Tue Oct 01 03:05:00 ICT 2013, cdate=2013-10-01T03:05:00.000+0700

Comment: Where is the incoming String come from?

Comment: I'm using form submission to save data. It is simple but I still dont know where the error come from

Comment: Either @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a") or @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"), I always got the same output "01/10/2013 03:05 AM"

Comment: @sharon I am facing the same problem. Have you found a solution yet? If so please update